# iOS - reuse EAAccessory object for reconnect?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, eaaccessory

I have an app connecting to classic Bluetooth using `EAAccessory` Framework.

I am trying to make it easier for user to connect 
by storing the `EAAccessory` object for reuse for next time the app start, that would automatically connect to the Bluetooth device,

Is this possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]];
```

for getting all accessory that are currently connected.

Answer (score 1):

As iOS does not allow you to control connection to/disconnection from a bluetooth device, storing a reference to an object that is not connected is redundant.

I have found that using EAAccessoryManager events like accessoryDidConnect and accessoryDidDisconnect to trigger connection to a device whose name or identifier (bluetooth address/MAC address) you have saved (instead of a reference to an EAAccessory) is both easier and more reliable than trying to reuse an EAAccessory that may no longer be relevant.

Comment: That assumes that the OS automatically reconnects to the Bluetooth device first, though, right? There is no way to initiate a re-connect from an iOS app that has once been connected to a BT device, provided that the device is still paired, or is there?

Comment: iOS does not allow you to control pairing with a bluetooth device, it handles that itself and notifies you through notifications that an accessory has connected/disconnected. If your app is running at the time an accessory connects you are able to check the accessory information to determine if this is the device your app wants to connect to. If your app is not running at the time the accessory connects, use the query in the below answer to get the currently connected accessories and determine if any of them are the one you are looking for.

Comment: I talk about connecting, not pairing. My question is not about getting notified (which I have under control) but having the connection re-established after the BT device was connected, then went out of range and then came back into reach. In the iOS System Prefs, the BT device remains listed as "not connected". Do you know what controls that automatic re-connection you suggest is happening (but not for our device)? Does the device have to initiate the reconnection or does iOS do that, do you know?

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9118. This seems to discuss what you are trying to do for Bluetooth LE devices. If the target hardware is classic Bluetooth you may be out of luck, but have a look into the MFI program documentation https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action which may shed some light on what you are trying to accomplish.